# xhttp.open path for node module

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm trying to build a node package
in my js code I've :

```
const calcHtml = './calc.html';
const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
      calcSelector.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    if (this.status == 404) {
      calcSelector.innerHTML = 'Page not found.';
    }
  }
};
xhttp.open('GET', calcHtml, true);
xhttp.send();
```

on local project dir no problem, the script find *calc.html*

But when I

> npm install

to another project

> const calc = require('modal-calculator');

I get => **GET http://localhost:8100/calc.html 404 (Not Found)**

Seems normal if *calc.html* is searched in "." dir... So, which path have I to specify to use *calc.html* from *node_modules\modal-calculator* please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding html directly in javascript and

```
calcSelector.innerHTML = "<div>Example</div>"
```